# How to merge AWS S3 bucket policies?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, content-security-policy

We have an existing S3 bucket policy in production:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy[redacted]",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ServiceA access",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::[redacted]:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mysite-production/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "ServiceA access",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::[redacted]:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mysite-production"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mysite-production/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

We have another 3rd party service we want to grant access which requires:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
             ],
             "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried merging the `ListAllMyBuckets` and `GetBucketLocation` into the final section of our original policy but that yields "Policy has invalid action" errors:

```
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
         ],
         "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mysite-production/*"
    }
```

How can I merge these into one cohesive policy? Or is it possible for a bucket to have two policies?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "3rd party service we want to grant access"? How are you identifying the 3rd party service — are they using a set of AWS credentials, or a particular AWS Account? This will determine _where_ you grant the access (either via a Bucket Policy or via an IAM policy).

Comment: `s3:ListAllMyBuckets` and `s3:GetBucketLocation` are not actions on objects; they are actions on buckets. So the associated resource cannot be `arn:aws:s3:::mysite-production/*`. It should be `arn:aws:s3:::*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can actually apply both IAM policies and S3 bucket policies
>   **simultaneously**, with the ultimate authorization being the least-privilege union of all the permissions.

Source: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/iam-policies-and-bucket-policies-and-acls-oh-my-controlling-access-to-s3-resources/